# My app button doesn't work, handler.java error

Tags: java, android, button, handler

I created a very simple quiz app and the button that should give you congrats after submitting the answer doesnt work at all. I see there are a lot of errors in the handler.java file so maybe that is the problem but I dont know what to do. (cant paste the handler file cause it goes beyond the limit of the post)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;   
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activity2 extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
    TextView intrebare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intrebare);
    Button buton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView rasplata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rasplata);

    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(View v) {
                                     final EditText raspuns = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.raspuns);
                                     if(raspuns.getText().toString() == "Bucuresti")
                                     {
                                         rasplata.setText("BRAVOO!!!");
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: What does it say in Logcat?

Comment: Lots of error in `handler.java` doesn't help. But in this code `(raspuns.getText().toString() == "Bucuresti"` should be `(raspuns.getText().toString().equals("Bucuresti")`.

Comment: Or "equalsIgnoreCase" in case it doesn't matter if it's capital letters or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Rohit5k2...  Try this:

```
  TextView intrebare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intrebare);
  Button buton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  final TextView rasplata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rasplata);

  buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          final EditText raspuns = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.raspuns);
          if (raspuns.getText().toString().equals("Bucuresti")) {
              rasplata.setText("BRAVOO!!!");
          }
      }
  });
```

Works great for me.